# MPAndroidChart - Y Axis labels draw to two lines (when too long)

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I'm using https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart library.

But I have too long descriptions on Y-axis. So I want to split it into two lines.

I tried to use '\n' and some other options but nothing was working.

How to achieve this in LineChart?

[image]